# Eutelsat 13G and Spacebus NEO's all-electric propulsion

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, orbital-maneuver, geostationary, electric-propulsion

Today, Eutelsat's Hotbird-13G was launched by a Falcon 9 to a "[geosynchronous transfer orbit](https://www.spacex.com/launches/eutelsat-hotbird-13g/)".

Deployment was at an altitude of roughly 1100 km. The satellite must reach a geosynchronous orbit from there. It is integrated into a [satellite bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_bus) which provides necessary services to its payload, in particular power and propulsion. The bus in this case is the [spacebus NEO](https://www.esa.int/Applications/Telecommunications_Integrated_Applications/Spacebus_Neo) developed by the Austrian company [RUAG](https://www.ruag.com/en). Its propulsion system is an all-electric plasma drive. I could not find much about it online.

How does it work? What's the reaction mass?

Related: How much energy is necessary to change orbits from 1,100 km to 36,000 km? I was surprised that an electric motor could do the job.

Comment: "Deployment was at an altitude of roughly 1100 km" – But not in a circular orbit. GTOs are highly elliptical with an apogee of – you guessed it – 36000 km.

Comment: My google-fu is weak with this bird. I'm not alone; for example, [Gunter's Space Page](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/hotbird-13f.htm), which is usually fairly good, lists the propulsion system with one symbol: "?".

Comment: Regarding the related comment, "I was surprised that an electric motor could do the job", once a vehicle gets on orbit, even LEO, electric propulsion can do the job -- eventually. The basic idea is to spiral out to the target orbit instead of going into a more direct transfer orbit. I've read somewhere that the optimal strategy with regard to propellant usage for low thrust / high specific impulse engines is to fire about 2/3 of the time. This might take weeks or even months. The twin vehicle Hotbed-13F was launched 3 weeks ago and is still moving toward the target orbit.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, I did moderate diligence and googled before I asked here. I basically hoped that a young ESA equivalent of Organic Marble would post some exploded assembly drawings of the bus ;-).

Comment: @JörgWMittag This vehicle (and its sister vehicle Hotbed-13F, which was launched about three weeks ago) were not inserted into what traditionally would be called GTO. They were instead inserted into an orbit with a much lower apogee than geosynchronous altitude. A traditional GTO requires high thrust to insert the vehicle into a geostationary orbit once the vehicle reaches geosynchronous altitude. That pretty much calls for chemical propulsion. The vehicles in question are all electric propulsion. They gradually spiral out to the target geostationary orbit.

Comment: Eutelsat Hotbird 13G is a Eurostar NEO platform, not a Spacebus NEO. The former are built by Airbus DS. Source: https://spacenews.com/spacex-launches-hotbird-3g-to-extend-eutelsats-broadcast-coverage/  As an aside the Spacebus NEO is built by Thales Alenia Space, not RUAG.

Comment: @Puffin Oh, thanks for the comment... I'll correct it when I have time. Maybe RUAG built only the drive? Anyway, if you find more please write an answer!